# Variables in a class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
@interface characterclass : CCSprite
{
    bool alive;
    int speed;
    int jumpamount = 10;  <--- error
}
@property bool alive;
@property int speed;
@property int jumpamount;
@end
```

how do i do this like in my code, I want to have a variable in my class that equals 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign these values in the initializer of your class's instances. Create an instance method called `- (id)init`:

```
- (id)init{
    self=[super init];
    if (self) {
        jumpamount=10;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note that you no longer need to declare your ivars like that. `@property` will create an ivar for you.